# How to create variable contain columns names for group by fonction?

Tags: python

I have a table contain 30 columns, and I want to apply in python this function

```
data = data.groupby(['Column1','Column2','Column4' .....,'Column30' ])['column3'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

I need to pass the names of the column with a variable like

```
a = 'Column1','Column2','Column4' .....,'Column30' 
data = data.groupby([a])['column3'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

but the system defines an as a string and look for column how is named by "column1,column2..."

Comment: Maybe you just need to remove the brackets when calling `groupby`: `data = data.groupby(a)['column3'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `groupby` on multiple columns, their names must be passed as a list:

`columns = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', ..., 'Column30']`

But I think this would work better in your case:

```
columns = data.columns.tolist()
data.groupby(columns)['Column3'].count()
```

Comment: @amalamal: And if you want to remove `Column3` from `columns`, use `columns = data.columns.difference('Column3').tolist()`.